N+1 issue when listing attachement and variants(has_many_attached)
N+1 query issue is coming at the time of fetching variant.
Model:
# Yoyaku Shouhin model
class YoyakuShouhin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :shouhin_images do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :desktop, resize: '500x500', gravity: 'center', format: :webp
    attachable.variant :mobile, resize: '400x400', gravity: 'center', format: :webp
    attachable.variant :desktop_l, resize: '700x700', gravity: 'center', format: :webp
  end
end

Query:
shouhins = YoyakuShouhin.includes(shouhin_images_attachments: :blob).order(:shouhin_number)

Feting all images:
object.shouhin_images.where(deleted: false).order('priority').map { |image| cdn_for(image.variant(:desktop).processed.key) }

N+1 query issue:
[active_model_serializers]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (25.7ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_variant_records"."variation_digest" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["blob_id", 17658], ["variation_digest", "dfN0cpZZzpYcgFl9hL0o122mIBI="], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (61.2ms)  COMMIT
[active_model_serializers]   ↳ app/serializers/api/v2/xmas/yoyaku_shouhin_serializer.rb:124:in `block in shouhin_mobile_images'
  ↳ app/middleware/request_response_history.rb:27:in `block in request_response_history'
[active_model_serializers]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (73.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 12079], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::VariantRecord"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   ↳ app/serializers/api/v2/xmas/yoyaku_shouhin_serializer.rb:124:in `block in shouhin_mobile_images'
[active_model_serializers]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (68.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 17659], ["LIMIT", 1]]

I want to solve n+1 query issue
